# Does the abelianization of the Galois group determine the ideal class group?

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideal-class-group

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field, assumed to be Galois, with Galois group

$G = Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$.

Is knowing the abelianization of $G$ alone, without other information on $K$, enough to determine the ideal class group of $K$? Or can we have two different Galois ANF $K_1$, $K_2$, having the same abelianization of their Galois groups, but non-isomorphic ideal class group?

I have just started learning the subject, so forgive the naiveness of my question.

Edit 1: this was answered below. I wonder if the answer would be any different if instead of

$G = Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$,

one replaces it with

$H = Gal(\bar{\mathbb{Q}} / K)$,

where $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The key point here in @RicardoBuring's counterexample is that both fields have the same Galois group, as well as the same abelianisation. The isomorphism class of $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ as an abstract group has nothing to do with the class group.

Comment: You should ask your edit as a new question. In short, the answer is that $H$ does determine the class group, via class field theory.

Comment: @Mathmo123, interesting! Thank you. All right, I will write a separate post.

Comment: Following a suggestion by @Mathmo123, I opened another post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3218399/does-this-galois-group-determine-the-class-ideal-class-group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, take e.g. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$. Both have Galois group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ but $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID whereas $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ is not principal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Comment: Nice. Thank you! I should study many examples. This is my plan.

Comment: I see. This has to do with the fact that $6$ can be written as $2$ times $3$, or as $1+\sqrt{5}$ times $1-\sqrt{5}$, in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Comment: Indeed. The explicit relation is that $(6) = (2,1+\sqrt{-5})^2(3,1+\sqrt{-5})(3,1-\sqrt{-5})$ as ideals, and you can get factorizations of $6$ as an element by multiplying out some of the ideals to get principal ideals. (See [my answer to How to factorise a number in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/993868/23180) for a more elaborate example.)

Comment: Is there a nice algorithmic way of getting all possible factorizations of an integer, knowing the corresponding factorization of the corresponding ideal as a product of prime ideals? The converse question is interesting too.